# Play Framework 2.8.2 - No Json serializer found for type (subclass)

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

I'm migrating some of my services from Play 2.7.x to the newest 2.8.2, together with scala 2.13.2 and sbt 1.3.12.

I'm hitting an obstacle with the play-json though, and the `Reads[A]`

I have the following setup:

```
sealed trait Charge {}
case class ChargeOne(one: Int) extends Charge
case class ChargeTwo(two: Int) extends Charge

object Charge {
  implicit val writes: Writes[Charge] = (charge: Charge) => {...}
}
```

We have some tests looking like so

```
val chargeOne = ChargeOne(1)
val json = Json.toJson(charge)

json mustBe "..."
```

And these work fine in play 2.7.x with scala 2.12.x, and it does also work with scala 2.13.2, but after upgrading play to 2.8.2, the following error occurs when compiling:

`No Json serializer found for type ChargeOne. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.`

And i have to add `.asInstanceOf[Charge]` to my tests to make it work.

What has happened here? Is it play-json? or is it scala? And does anyone know how to "fix" it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated in the error message, an instance of `Writes` (or a `Format`) for `ChargeOne` is required, whereas the code only provide a `Reads`.

```
import play.api.libs.json._ // BTW Recommend to provide import in code examples

sealed trait Charge {}
case class ChargeOne(one: Int) extends Charge
case class ChargeTwo(two: Int) extends Charge

object Charge {
  implicit val format: OFormat[Charge] = {
    // Need to define instance for the subtypes (no auto-materialization)
    implicit def one = Json.format[ChargeOne]
    implicit def two = Json.format[ChargeTwo]

    Json.format[Charge]
  }
}
```

Then you can see that `Writes` and `Reads` are invariant (typeclasses) so only resolved for parent type `Charge`:

```
scala> Json.toJson(ChargeOne(1))
<console>:17: error: No Json serializer found for type ChargeOne. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
       Json.toJson(ChargeOne(1))
                  ^

scala> Json.toJson(ChargeOne(1): Charge)
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"one":1,"_type":"ChargeOne"}
```

If you don't want to have to annotate on each `toJson`:

```
import play.api.libs.json._ // BTW Recommend to provide import in code examples

sealed trait Charge {}
case class ChargeOne(one: Int) extends Charge
case class ChargeTwo(two: Int) extends Charge

object Charge {
  implicit val format: OFormat[Charge] = {
    // Need to define instance for the subtypes (no auto-materialization)
    implicit def one = Json.format[ChargeOne]
    implicit def two = Json.format[ChargeTwo]

    Json.format[Charge]
  }

  implicit def genericWrites[T <: Charge]: OWrites[T] =
    format.contramap[T](c => c: Charge)

  implicit def genericReads[T <: Charge](implicit evidence: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]): Reads[T] = format.collect[T](JsonValidationError(s"Type mismatch: ${evidence.runtimeClass.getName}")) {
    case `evidence`(t) => t
  }
}
    
scala> Json.toJson(ChargeOne(1))
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"one":1,"_type":"ChargeOne"}

scala> Json.toJson(ChargeOne(1)).validate[Charge]
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Charge] = JsSuccess(ChargeOne(1),)
```

**Note#1**: It's important to see that (de)serialization `ChargeOne` (or any subtype) as `Charge` (or any similar parent type) to/from JSON is not the same as doing it "directly". The JSON representation is not the same as sealed family serialization requires a discriminator JSON field (see `_type`).

```
scala> Json.writes[ChargeOne].writes(ChargeOne(1))
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"one":1}

scala> Json.toJson(ChargeOne(1)) // .. as Charge parent type
res2: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"one":1,"_type":"ChargeOne"}
```

**Note#2:** If some similar use cases were wrongly working in previous versions, it was leading to hardly predictable JSON representation, and critical implicit resolution in a lot of cases, which is the reason for this behavior change/fix (see [pull request](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/pull/216)).

Comment: I have edited my question, as this happens to both read and writes on subclasses of my sealed trait, and i copy/pasted the wrong error into this question.

Comment: Thats also a possibility to use OFormat. I didn't know about that. Will give it a go. Thanks for your answer. Will post back and accept if it works as expected

Comment: Facing an issue where, when adding a `reads[T <: Charge]: Reads[T]`method, the `OFormat` can only return a `Charge` and not a `T <: Charge`

Comment: See the answer pls

Comment: Your solution works. 

It still doesn't make sense to me, to remove the capability for play-json to detect this by itself. (the code in my question works just fine in play 2.7.3, without reflection and other shenannigans).

Comment: See the explanation. It may have work in this specific case in 2.7 (due to `Writes` contravariance before 2.8), but that raise a lot more issue in other case. The current state is more stable and nominal (and no plan to revert that).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: I have almost similar problem where it could not find "_type". The error says "error.missing.path". I understand we have to provide `_type` discriminator. But because this data is coming from third party API, I can not inject any data into it. So what I did is to provide default value in my case class like following.
`case class ChargeOne(_type: String = "ChargeOne", one: Int) extends Charge`
But this does not solve the problem. Any idea what I can do in this case?

Comment: Use provided utilities and combinator to add missing discriminator. That being said, a json serializer that write such data without discriminator is buggy anyway.