# Json.writes for sealed trait

Tags: scala, play-json

How to deserialize a sealed trait. I am using play JSON framework. I have read many post for writing companion object. Does anyone know how to write for `Json.writes`?

```
sealed trait DataFormat             
case object JSON extends DataFormat                      
case object INVALID extends DataFormat
```

Comment: Please format properly your code in questions

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonAutomated#Requirements), the `Reads`/`OWrites`/`OFormat` instances for sealed family (sealed trait and subtypes) can be generated using `Json.{read,write,format}` macros.

```
import play.api.libs.json._

sealed trait DataFormat
case object JsonFormat extends DataFormat
case object InvalidFormat extends DataFormat

object DataFormat {
  implicit val format: OFormat[DataFormat] = {
    implicit def jsf = Json.format[JsonFormat.type]
    implicit def ivf = Json.format[InvalidFormat.type]

    Json.format[DataFormat]
  }
}
```

> Please use the [Scala naming](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html), and do not name types (classes, objects, traits in UPPERCASE).

Then:

```
scala> Json.toJson[DataFormat](JsonFormat)
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"_type":"JsonFormat"}

scala> Json.toJson(InvalidFormat: DataFormat)
res2: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"_type":"InvalidFormat"}
```

You can have a look at [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62592017/play-framework-2-8-2-no-json-serializer-found-for-type-subclass/62592922#62592922) for the limitations.

You could also have a look at [Enumeratum support for Play-JSON](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum#play-json) (to use enumerated types with Play-JSON).

---

*About alternative code in comment:*

```
object DataFormat {
  // Note: dataFormatObject is not an object name according Scala naming
  implicit object DataFormatObject extends Format[DataFormat] {
    implicit def reads(json: JsValue) = json match {
      case JsString("JSON") =>
        JsSuccess(JSON)
      case _ =>
        JsError(INVALID.toString)
    }

    implicit def writes(dataFormat: DataFormat) =
      JsString(dataFormat.toString)
  }
}

// No need to define it again as available in companion object
implicit lazy val dataFormatWrites: Format[DataFormat] =
  DataFormat.dataFormatObject
```

So there is wrong naming and `val dataFormatWrites` is not need.

If you want to represent enumerated type in Play JSON, I strongly advice to have a look at Enumeratum-Play-JSON as mentioned previously.
Anyway it can be done by composing already provided `Reads[String]` and `Writes[String]` instances.

```
import play.api.libs.json._

sealed trait DataFormat
case object JsonFormat extends DataFormat
case object InvalidFormat extends DataFormat

object DataFormat {
  implicit def writes: Writes[DataFormat] =
    implicitly[Writes[String]]. // Resolve default `Writes[String]`
      contramap[DataFormat] {
        case JsonFormat => "JSON"
        case _ => "INVALID"
      }

  implicit def reads: Reads[DataFormat] =
    implicitly[Reads[String]]. // Resolve default `Reads[String]`
      collect[DataFormat](JsonValidationError("Unsupported DataFormat")) {
        case "JSON" => JsonFormat
        case _ => InvalidFormat
      }
}

scala> Json.toJson[DataFormat](JsonFormat)
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = "JSON"

scala> Json.toJson(InvalidFormat: DataFormat)
res3: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = "INVALID"

scala> JsString("JSON").validate[DataFormat]
res4: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[DataFormat] = JsSuccess(JsonFormat,)

scala> JsString("INVALID").validate[DataFormat]
res5: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[DataFormat] = JsSuccess(InvalidFormat,)
```

Moreover, I would not define `case object InvalidFormat`, as it doesn't represent a format, but rather an error when trying to work with supported format.
That's where validation types are useful, there with Play-JSON it's `JsResult`, so `InvalidFormat` should rather be a `JsError[DataFormat]`.

```
import play.api.libs.json._

sealed trait DataFormat
case object JsonFormat extends DataFormat
case object AnotherFormat extends DataFormat // at least 2 subtypes, otherwise no need to have a DataFormat trait but rather directly use JsonFormat

object DataFormat {
  implicit def writes: Writes[DataFormat] =
    implicitly[Writes[String]]. // Resolve default `Writes[String]`
      contramap[DataFormat] {
        case JsonFormat => "JSON"
        case AnotherFormat => "ANOTHER"
      }

  implicit def reads: Reads[DataFormat] =
    implicitly[Reads[String]]. // Resolve default `Reads[String]`
      collect[DataFormat](JsonValidationError("Invalid DataFormat")) {
        case "JSON" => JsonFormat
        case "ANOTHER" => AnotherFormat
      }
}
```

So then:

```
scala> Json.toJson[DataFormat](JsonFormat)
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = "JSON"

scala> Json.toJson(AnotherFormat: DataFormat)
res2: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = "ANOTHER"

scala> JsString("JSON").validate[DataFormat]
res3: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[DataFormat] = JsSuccess(JsonFormat,)

scala> JsString("ANOTHER").validate[DataFormat]
res4: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[DataFormat] = JsSuccess(AnotherFormat,)

scala> JsString("FOO").validate[DataFormat]
res5: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[DataFormat] = JsError(List((,List(JsonValidationError(List(Invalid DataFormat),WrappedArray())))))
```

Comment: object DataFormat {
    implicit object dataFormatObject extends Format[DataFormat] {
      implicit def reads(json: JsValue) =
        json match {
          case JsString("JSON") => JsSuccess(JSON)
          case _                => JsError(INVALID.toString)
        }
      implicit def writes(dataFormat: DataFormat) =
        JsString(dataFormat.toString)
    }
  }
implicit lazy val dataFormatWrites: Format[DataFormat] =
    DataFormat.dataFormatObject                    




I wrote like this is this also fine?

Comment: yes thanks,but which one should I use,the one you told or the later one?

Comment: The answer explains, but you should rather use enumeratum

Comment: hey, say I only have a writer and I don't want/need this additional "_type" field, is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: Writing without a discriminator would be a bad idea, as data won't be readable, or not readable without a much more complex logic to detect the struct type.